# Changing a datafield into a database in selenium testcase: django python

Tags: python, django, django-models, selenium

There is this field in my database which is

> package_expiry_date

, now I want to change its value from selenium test case itself to use it after a while. like extend the date by 5 days by adding

> datetime.timedelta(days=5)

. How can I change its value in database table, in python selenium testcase for django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium API enables you to interact with a web page and various web elements on it.

To change any value in your database will have have to do that based on which database you are using and which python methods are using to interact with this database provider.
(For eg - one will use JDBC when using Java language)

It has nothing to do with selenium or it's API.